# Export to Excel on Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, xlsx

```
exportAsExcelFile(json: any[], excelFileName: string): void {
  const worksheet: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.table_to_sheet(json);
  const workbook: XLSX.WorkBook = {
    Sheets: {
      'data': worksheet
    },
    SheetNames: ['data']
  };
  XLSX.writeFile(workbook, `${excelFileName}_${new Date().toLocaleDateString()}.xlsx`);
}
```

I didn't download to file.I didn't encounter this problem on PC, I only have any problem with Tablet.

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: I didn't download to file.I didn't encounter this problem on PC, I only have any problem with Tablet.

Answer (score 0):

> This may help you

You need to created `ExcelService`

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-export-xlsx

Comment: lib recommendations should be comments, not answers

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array
you can use `json_to_sheet()`:

```js
import {writeFileXLSX, utils} from 'xlsx';

///...

exportToExcel(): void {
    const data = this.data$.getValue();
    const excelBook = utils.book_new();
    const excelSheet = utils.json_to_sheet(data);
    utils.book_append_sheet(excelBook, excelSheet, 'sheet_name');
    writeFileXLSX(excelBook, "table.xlsx");
}
```